# How can I pass a string as where clause to a function?

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFooData() 
RETURNS TABLE(foo_name name text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select foo_name from foo where x = 3;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

into this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFooData( IN criteria text ) 
RETURNS TABLE(foo_name name text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select foo_name from foo where $1; -- > I CAN'T DO THIS
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I need to create a flexible query criteria in my function or else I'll be in a nightmare to create several functions to cover all `foo` fields combinations and pass only the values thru parameter. The problem is in some situations I may use `foo.x, foo.y and foo.z` in other I may use `foo.h, foo.x`. I may use any fields in search criteria in any combinations.

Comment: A newbie question about this: Does it make any difference (performance) to use `select * from getFooData() where x = 3` or `getFooData( 'x=3' )` and leave the `where` to the function?

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for this.

Comment: @MagnoC the former only works if the function returns `x`

Comment: @dezso yeap. I know in case of using the `external` selection I'll need to externalyze all `foo` fields. I' ve done a small performance test and will post here as answer. No named horse I'll give it a try.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  After read the docs, my question is about `...If multiple rows are returned, only the first will be assigned to the INTO variable...` I need to return a table. My function return is `RETURN QUERY SELECT * from foo where bar = snafu`. Any sugestion?

Comment: You can return multiple rows with dynamic SQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65722

Comment: Just added `RETURNS SETOF foo AS` and `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql ... ` but I'm facing another problem: I'm returning all `foo` structure plus two other values... how can I solve this?

Comment: Removed `RETURNS SETOF foo AS` and added `RETURNS TABLE( <foo fields> plus <my fields>)` seems to be working...

Comment: Worked. Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Following the Horse's answer/comment, this is my final version of my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pointscanner(IN routegeometry text, IN criteria text)
  RETURNS TABLE(way geometry, name text, distance double precision, tags hstore, operator text, admin_level text, z_order integer) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    geomRoute geometry;
    routeBB box2d;
    sql text;
BEGIN
    geomRoute = ST_GeomFromText( $1 ,4326);

    routeBB := ST_Extent(geomRoute);


    sql := 'SELECT pt.way, pt.name, ST_Distance( $1, ST_Transform(pt.way,4326) ) * 111195 as distance, pt.tags, pt.operator, pt.admin_level, pt.z_order '
     || ' FROM planet_osm_point pt where $2 && ST_Transform(pt.way,4326) and ' || criteria;


    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql USING geomRoute, routeBB;


END; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Called as: `select * from pointscanner(<first_arg>, 'x = 3') where second selection`

Performance test: `must I put the selecion criteria inside or leave it outside a function?`

In this test I create a functio that select some records in a OpenStreetMap table. This is the heart of the function:

Function **pointscanner():**

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT pt.way, pt.name, ST_Distance( geomRoute, ST_Transform(pt.way,4326) ) * 111195 
as distance, pt.tags, pt.operator, pt.admin_level, pt.z_order 
FROM planet_osm_point pt
where routeBB && ST_Transform(pt.way,4326)
```

The fact is: I must do a second selection (fine tunning) in the function result. Must I do this inside the function and pass the selecion parameters or I can do it outside the function?

Selection exemple: `name is not null`

**Option 1: a `where` clause inside the function:**

Change function to:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT pt.way, pt.name, ST_Distance( geomRoute, ST_Transform(pt.way,4326) ) * 111195 
as distance, pt.tags, pt.operator, pt.admin_level, pt.z_order 
FROM planet_osm_point pt
where routeBB && ST_Transform(pt.way,4326) and pt.name is not null;
```

Call it as: `select * from pointscanner() where round(distance::numeric, 5) < 500`

Result:

```
"Function Scan on pointscanner  (cost=0.25..17.75 rows=333 width=172) 
    (actual time=1251.040..1251.792 rows=358 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (round((distance)::numeric, 5) < '500'::numeric)"
"Planning time: 0.074 ms"
"Execution time: 1251.867 ms"
```

**Option 1: a `where` clause outside the function:**

Leave the function untouched.

Call it as: `select * from pointscanner() where round(distance::numeric, 5) < 500 and name is not null`

Result:

```
"Function Scan on pointscanner  (cost=0.25..17.75 rows=332 width=172)
    (actual time=4654.345..4655.075 rows=358 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((name IS NOT NULL) AND (round((distance)::numeric, 5) < '500'::numeric))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 238"
"Planning time: 0.114 ms"
"Execution time: 4655.161 ms"
```

So I conclude I MUST do the second selection criteria INSIDE the function.